# Can I simplify using Observable.Create to return objects from a json request

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have been making my web request like this:

```
public IObservable<Foo> GetFoo(string fooId)
{
    var uri = /* set up the GET query parameters here */;

    return Observable.Create<Foo>(
        obs => new HttpClient().GetAsync(uri)
            .ToObservable()
            .Subscribe(response =>
            {
                try
                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                        .ToObservable()
                        .Select(JObject.Parse)
                        .Select(json => new Foo(json))
                        .Subscribe(foo =>
                        {
                            obs.OnNext(foo);
                            obs.OnCompleted();
                        });
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    obs.OnError(e);
                }
            }));
```

}

However, I feel that as a relative newcomer to Rx, I might be missing some way of simplifying what I've written. It seems the outer `Observable` is just a wrapper around the inner one, and I could (somehow) expose that, instead --I just don't know how.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
return Observable.Defer(() => HttpClient().GetAsync(uri))
    .SelectMany(async x => { x.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); return x.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); })
    .Select(JObject.Parse)
    .Select(json => new Foo(json));
```

The `Observable.Defer` here makes it match the semantics of your original method wrt subscriptions (i.e. you subscribe twice, you make 2 HTTP requests).

Comment: `Observable.Using` would make this perfect.

Comment: @CoryNelson, how would `Using` improve this?

Comment: Thanks! I knew Rx would have some way to do what I'm doing in a much more concise fashion.

Comment: @CoryNelson I don't think anything needs to be disposed here, not sure you need the Using

Comment: `HttpClient` and `HttpResponseMessage` are both disposable.

Comment: I prefer `Observable.FromAsync` to `Observable.Defer` - no functional difference but it makes the code slightly more readable to me. It does have overloads for mapping subscription disposal to cancellation tokens, but you can also find these on `Observable.DeferAsync`.

Comment: @JamesWorld Thanks, I agree that `FromAsync` is more readable. It also removes the warning about an awaitable being ignored.

Comment: hwhoops, I fixed the warning, but FromAsync works great too :)